# Position of side bar menu to top

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have one web page it includes the the page sidebar.php.This menu appears at the left side of the web page verticaly.I want this to be on the top of the page and display horizantally.I could not identify the class which keeps it on the left side.I am not posting the css file.Kindly help me to keep it on the top.Though my code is length still iam posting it here.I am net very familiar with css .

```
    <aside id="slide-out" class="side-nav white fixed">
                <div class="side-nav-wrapper">
                    <div class="sidebar-profile">
                        <div class="sidebar-profile-image">
                            <img src="../assets/images/profile-image.png" class="circle" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="sidebar-profile-info">
                       
                                <p>Admin</p>

                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                <ul class="sidebar-menu collapsible collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
                    <li class="no-padding"><a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="dashboard.php"><i class="material-icons">settings_input_svideo</i>Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="no-padding">
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey"><i class="material-icons">apps</i>Department<i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="adddepartment.php">Add Department</a></li>
                                <li><a href="managedepartments.php">Manage Department</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="no-padding">
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey"><i class="material-icons">account_box</i>Recommending Officer<i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="addagm.php">Add Recommending Officer</a></li>
                                <li><a href="manageagm.php">Manage Recommending Officer</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                  <!--  <li class="no-padding">
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey"><i class="material-icons">desktop_windows</i>Stationary Type<i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="addstationarytype.php">Add Stationary Type</a></li>
                                <li><a href="managestationarytype.php">Manage Stationary Type</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>-->
                    <li class="no-padding">
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey"><i class="material-icons">account_box</i>Employees<i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="addemployee.php">Add Employee</a></li>
                                <li><a href="manageemployee.php">Manage Employee</a></li>
       
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

   <li class="no-padding">
                        <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect waves-grey"><i class="material-icons">desktop_windows</i>Stationary Management<i class="nav-drop-icon material-icons">keyboard_arrow_right</i></a>
                        <div class="collapsible-body">
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="addstationarystock.php"   target="popup"  onclick="window.open('addstationarystock.php','popup','height=600,width=900 top=15 left=300,location=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no, scrollbars=no'); return false;">Add Stationary Stock</a></li>
                                <li><a href="leaves.php">All Stationary Request </a></li>
                                <li><a href="pending-leavehistory.php">Pending Request </a></li>
                                <li><a href="approvedleave-history.php">Approved Request</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="notapproved-leaves.php">Not Approved Request</a></li>
       
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>


  <li class="no-padding"><a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="changepassword.php"><i class="material-icons">settings_input_svideo</i>Chnage Password</a></li>

                        <li class="no-padding">
                                <a class="waves-effect waves-grey" href="logout.php"><i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i>Sign Out</a>
                            </li>  
                 

                 
              
                </ul>
                   <div class="footer">
                    <p class="copyright"><a href="#">SMS </a>©</p>
                
                </div>
                </div>
            </aside>
```

Comment: How can we help you without your css? 
Anyway the class could be "side-nav", but i can't know it

Comment: @AndreaViviani I DIDNT FIND ANY THING ON THAT .Can i change the cSS